# Text changes to white when i remove focus

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Video example: http://recordit.co/HsWMaQGapR

I cannot figure out why this is happening. I am using Bootstrap. Here's the css i'm using.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
background: transparent;
color: #b0babf !important;
```

}

Comment: can you post a fiddle ? i mean minimum code that reproduce the problem on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. I simply needed to override Bootstrap default styles.

Like so:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
color: #b0babf !important;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `:focus` selector to style the text colour from what I understand from a quick scan. What that obviously means is that when the focus is removed, the colour will go back to what it was specified as prior in your CSS. That must probably be white, I suppose.